# The meaning of the context: passive to active voice

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Our study suggests that those factors in mission statements that are most associated with financial performance can be viewed as indicators of a socially responsible company.

(The above sentence is from a journal)

I have a hard time trying to understand the meaning of the sentence,

**that are most associated with financial performance** modifies "factors" instead of the preceding noun "mission statements" , is that right?

Can the sentence be viewed in active voice?:

> We can view those factors in mission statements that are most associated with financial performance as indicators of a socially responsible company.

Comment: It's ambiguous. 1. (Factors in mission statements) that are most associated with financial performance; or 2. Factors in (mission statements that are most associated with financial performance).